# Not plotting NA-Values in raster with python

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, masking

I have a raster that I cropped beforehand based on a shapefile with

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata '-1000 -255' -cutline {shape} {vrt_path} {tiff_path}
```

The thing is, that there are many NAs that get simply plotted as black pixels. The shapefile is ways smaller than the raster and when I plot it with rasterio, I barely can see anything of the raster. How could I mask the NA-Values out, so that they aren't part anymore of the raster?

Answer (score 1):

You could try rioxarray: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html

```py
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
rds.rio.clip(geoms, drop=True).rio.to_raster(...)
```